# expired form error when return from offline payment in cartthrob payment plugin

Tags: cartthrob, error, expire

i create payment plugin for cartthrob in EE.
in this plugin we need to send parameter to gateway website with POST and gateway website will return result with posting parameter to url we gave it.
everything goes OK but when gateway send parameter to our url we get error.

```
This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.
```

gateway post data to:

http://example.com/themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib/extload.php/Mellat

when we call that URL without post data its working...

thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am getting the same error with SagePay

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this. I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

EE's "secure forms" feature requires that all POST requests contain a valid `XID` (or `crsf_token` in 2.8+). The POST back from your gateway contains no such token, hence the issue.

So you either need to disable secure forms (not recommended), or register an action for your payment plugin, and set `crsf_exempt` to `1` when you do so. Then use that action URL for your gateway to POST back to.